# How to use IEnumerable instead of List?

Tags: c#, list, asp.net-core-mvc, ienumerable

I wanted to implement list of transactions and add them to a model with a query like this:

My controller:

```
List<Transaction> transactionLists = new List<Transaction>();

        using (var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connString))
        {
            string query = "SELECT t.transaction_id, a.account_name, a.type, t.amount, t.date " +
                           "FROM account AS a " +
                           "INNER JOIN transaction AS t ON a.account_id = t.account_id;";
            List<Transaction> transactions = connection.Query<Transaction>(query) as List<Transaction>;
            transactionLists.AddRange(transactions);
        }
```

but, Instead I wanted to implement it with IEnumerable, without using list like this:

```
        public IActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.accounts = GetAccountLists().OrderByDescending(x => x.AccountName).ToList();

        IEnumerable<Transaction> transactions;

        using (var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connString))
         {
            transactions = connection.Query<Transaction>(@"SELECT t.transaction_id, a.account_name, a.type, t.amount, t.date
                                                           FROM account AS a
                                                           INNER JOIN transaction AS t ON a.account_id = t.account_id");
             //transactionLists.AddRange(transactions);
         }
        var model = new TransactionViewModel();
        model.Transactions = transactions;
        return View(model);
    }
```

and also avoid using another using another variable here - `transactionLists`.Instead ojust want to return from Dapper itself?

How do I do that?

Comment: `transactionLists.AddRange(transactions);` Why are you copying the contents of one list into another? Why not just assign the result? Which is what you are doing when you change the type of the variable.

Comment: @jeremy Lakeman: HI, That is what I have a problem with, I don't know how to assign results directly without using a list. can you tell me how to do it with IEnumerable?

Comment: Don't you want `IEnumerable<Transaction> t = Query(...).ToList()`  ? eg `t` *is* a list, but you don't need to know that.

Comment: `var model = new TransactionViewModel();` move this before `using` block. ` `model.Transactions = connection.Query<Transaction>(@"SELECT....` writs this inside `using` block.

Answer (score 1):

Chetan and Jeremy are saying you can structure this:

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.accounts = GetAccountLists().OrderByDescending(x => x.AccountName).ToList();

        using var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connString);
      
        var model = new TransactionViewModel();
        model.Transactions = connection.Query<Transaction>(@"
SELECT t.transaction_id, a.account_name, a.type, t.amount, t.date
FROM account AS a
INNER JOIN transaction AS t ON a.account_id = t.account_id").ToList();

        return View(model);
    }
```

Assuming a TransactionViewModel has an `IEnumerable<Transaction> Transactions` property. You're allowed to assign a `List<Transaction>` to an `IEnumerable<Transaction>` because a List implements IEnumerable. I wasn't in a position to  check, but I expect you'll need a ToList or something similar on the end of the Dapper query in order to materialize (download) the data from the database before the executing thread leaves this method. Feel free to try it without, but if you get an ObjectDisposedException you'll be running into the reasonably common gotcha with deferred execution that the results you want are read when you enumerate the enumerable, but if the db connection has been disposed of it won't be able to provide any data